# Having one FTP account with multiple concurrent logins?

Tags: ftp, ftp-server

I am having deep thoughts about how to use a FTP server. I am having an application, where I want some user files to be stored on a FTP server. So what I am doing is when user save his/her file on the server side I am opening a connection to the FTP and saves the file. After the file is saved the connection is closed. Because I will have many users using my system simultaniously, so the question is what is the best way to do that- to set the FTP server settings, for example, to allow 1000 simultanious logins and to use a different FTP account for every file upload or to set max-threads to 1000 and to use one ftp account for all user uploads? In my oppinion because the connection is live only for the time the file is uploading it won't be a problem to use one account with multiple threds, but I want to hear someone else oppinion what is the best practise to do that kind of functionality? Thanks.

Comment: 1. `ftp` is really old, insecure and a nightmare for network administrators. Sure you cannot use the more modern and more secure `sftp` instead? 2. it is not true that each file transfer requires a separate connection, actually in contrary: typically one opens a single connection and then transfers one file after another within that connection.

Comment: What I wonder is how to implement it- to use one ftp account for all my users in the application or to have a different ftp account for every user. In other words- will the ftp act as I want if I use one ftp account for all the user uploads even if there are a lot simultanious uploads? The workflow of my application is- the user start the upload of a file, the application server opens connection to the ftp server, login with the account, transfer the file and disconnects from the ftp.

Comment: My personal feeling would be that the prime reason to use multiple accounts would be to segregate data belonging to different users. If that is not necessary, you would likely save yourself lots of configuration and trouble managing maultiple accounts and passwords and get much the same performance if you lumped all users' data in together.

Comment: How do you want to use separate ftp accounts in such a setup? You want to create a new account on the ftp server for each user you register in whatever system that is users upload files to? Why? What for? And how? besides it would not be a logical thing to do: from the ftp servers view there is only _one_ client: that application doing the upload.

Comment: Yep, I thought so, but I wanted to hear different opinions. @MarkSetchell, yes I want to separate the data, but finally one client is doing everything- the application server as arkascha said. Thanks for the answers :)